# swift func: i can't understand underscore as a parameter name that can compile

Tags: swift, func

how to use underscore parameter

```
func test(currentName name: String, _: Int) {

    print("aa\(name) abc");
    //how to use  _  parameter?
}

test(currentName:"aa", 3)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270732/what-do-and-in-mean-in-swift-programming-language
it is a placeholder parameter name. _ means it will not  be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` means when you call `test` function, you don't have to write the text before the second parameter `test(currentName:"aa", 3)`

if you declare your function like this:

```
func test(currentName name: String, secondParameter: Int) {    
    print("aa\(name) abc");
    //how to use  _  parameter?
}
```

then when you call `test` function, you must to call like this:

```
test(currentName:"aa", secondParameter: 3)
```

Comment: func like following  
func test(currentName name: String, _: Int) {
print("aa\(name) abc");
//how to use  _  parameter?
}

Comment: @Blue joy we can' use _ in function body as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift, functions have both parameter labels and parameter names. This is for clarity when using the functions. Think about a normal C function, it is declared as such:

```
string FunctionName(string firstName, string lastName)
```

Looking at the function declaration, it's easy to see what each parameter is. In this case, a firstName and a lastName. However when it is called in code, it's less apparent, particularly if the parameter values aren't self-describing. eg:

```
FunctionName("Neil","Armstrong") // Fairly obvious

FunctionName("Bo","Ng") // Not so obvious
```

In swift, parameters have both labels and names. Labels are there purely for clarity, so the code that calls the function can be read and understood more easily, without having to dive into its definition to fully understand it

```
let fullName = funcName(firstName: "Bo", lastName: "Ng")
```

In some cases, the parameter name is entirely unnecessary, eg:

```
let total = addTwoNumbers(1,2)
```

So the labels are optional, denoted by an underscore

```
func addTwoNumbers(_ firstVal:Int,_ secondVal:Int)
```

Generally speaking, you should use labels to make the functions you write clearer, unless you feel the parameters are entirely self-describing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use second parameter of function but don't want to "name" it, you have to change signature of function to `func test(currentName name: String, age _: Int)` and then refer to second argument as `age`.

```
func test(currentName name: String, _ age: Int) {
    print("Name: \(name), age: \(age)")
}

test(name: "Piter", 3)
```

Comment: You have currentName and name swapped in the first line there.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeJfromVA! I have fixed it.